# Do too many google chart scripts affect adsense loading

Tags: javascript, google-adsense

I have a fairly dynamic website that uses google visualization api. (Every page displays 6 to 10 charts.)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart','line']});</script>
```

Google loads several js files as a result of the above call:

```
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_format_module.js
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_default_module.js
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_corechart_module.js
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/third_party/dygraphs/dygraph-tickers-combined.js
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/third_party/webfontloader/webfont.js
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.2/js/jsapi_compiled_line_module.js
```

Does large number of javascript files affect adsense? I am asking this because I am observing adsense slots going blank in these pages quite often.

Note: Though the page contains lots of charts, there is plenty of text content as well. Hence, I guess lack of keywords triggering ads shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Blank AdSense slots are usually caused by a lack of ad inventory.  Even if Google knows what your site is about, it may not have enough ads to fill all the slots.  I've also seen blank ads when Google only fills the first slot.   Sometimes Google determines that you are more likely to get a click with just one ad on the page.    I doubt that it is the the chart JS interfering, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Since I posted the original question, I am observing that the adsense coverage is improving steadily. Hence as you pointed out may be the issue was with inventory. Progressively the adsense crawler seems to be picking up context and filling up the slots.